# Unable to create nettcp port binding on IIS website

Tags: binding, iis-7, activation, net.tcp

I have been attempting to create a nettcp port binding on the IIS default website for the port 9999; however always get the following error from the net.tcp listener;

> An error occurred while parsing the net.tcp binding '9999:*' of the site '1', thus the protocol is disabled for the site temporarily. See the exception message for more details.
>    Binding: net.tcp:9999:*
>    Source: System.ServiceModel.Activation.ListenerAdapter/12547953
>    Exception: System.UriFormatException: The protocol binding '9999:*' is not valid for 'net.tcp'.  This might be because the port number is out of range.
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BaseUriWithWildcard..ctor(String protocol, Int32 defaultPort, String binding, Int32 segmentCount, String path, String sampleBinding)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BaseUriWithWildcard.CreateHostedUri(String protocol, String binding, String path)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ListenerAdapter.RegisterBindings(IActivatedMessageQueue queue, Int32 siteId, String[] bindings, String path)
>    Process Name: SMSvcHost
>    Process ID: 1120

Anyone have any ideas on what could be the problem? Or an approach on how we might be able to investigate the issue further? I have checked the firewall settings and it seems the port is not specifically blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my *Net.TCP listener adapter service* had stopped running for some reason; turning this on resolved the issue. Steps given below;

1. On the server; open Services from Administrative Tools
2. Verify that the Net.Pipe Listener Adapter or the Net.Tcp Listener Adapter service is running. If not, right-click on the service and click Start.

Saurabh Chowdhury's answer above is also a common troubleshooting step; however this was not the issue in my case.

This [link](https://rohitguptablog.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/configuring-wcf-service-with-nettcpbinding/) also gives a good overview of some of the other points to look out for.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that Non-HTTP Activation feature is installed on the machine.
[image: WCF Activation - Windows Features]